# Detecting connection state not working as expected in Node environment

Tags: firebase

In the offline capabilities section for Web, it is described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state) how to detect if the client is connected to the internet or not. However, Firebase doesn't seem to call the event handler every time a client connects or disconnects when running in Node environment. It works as expected when running in the browser i.e. it calls the event handler every time the client is connected or disconnected from the internet.

Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varungupta85/1swuwf7r/3/). Once you run the fiddle and you connect or disconnect from the internet, you will see a corresponding 'connected' or 'disconnected' message in the console.

I ran the below code in Node which is exactly same as the code I ran in browser. While running in Node environment, I observed that I received the initial 'connected' and 'disconnected' message but if I connected and disconnected from the internet again, no messages are printed meaning that the event handler is not called

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ref = new Firebase("<FIREBASE-APP>");

var connectedRef = ref.child(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    console.log("connected");
  } else {
    console.log("not connected");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran the same script in node on my system:

```
$ node connected.js
```

> not connected
>
> connected
>
> not connected
>
> connected

The first two come from the initial start of the script. The last two log lines came after I turned the wifi of my laptop off for a minute and then on again.

It may take some time before the Firebase client detects that it lost the connection to its servers, so be patient. The reason for the time it takes depends on the environment (browser/node) you run in, since the Firebase client depends on that environment to provide the WebSocket and detect time-outs.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I guess I was being a little impatient. I ran the script again and on my mac book, it took ~200 seconds on average to detect that the connection has been lost. When I connect to internet, it detects that in a couple of seconds which is good. In the browser however, both the events are detected almost instantaneously. Any reason why there would be such a big difference to detect that connection has been lost in node environment vs browser? On my windows machine, it took ~50 seconds to detect that connection has been lost which is not as bad as 200 seconds.

Comment: My Macbook air took exactly a minute. It really depends on the OS and environment your code runs in. I added some more info on that.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. Thanks!